# LinqToTwitter status update only works sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, async-await, linq-to-twitter

I'm trying to send a tweet using `LinqToTwitter`. My problem is that it almost never works. I've gotten it to work maybe three times out of thirty, and usually that's when I try to debug. I'm thinking it might have something to do with timing and authentication, but I don't know how to do it. The code runs without errors, but no tweet is generated.

```
public static async Task SendTweetAsync(string text)
    {
        // Get the authorization credentials
        var auth = GetCredentials();

        // Create the twitter context
        var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);

        try
        {
            Status responseTweet = await ctx.TweetAsync(text);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private static AspNetAuthorizer GetCredentials()
    {
        return new AspNetAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore()
            {
                ConsumerSecret = "##########",
                ConsumerKey = "##########",
                OAuthToken = "##########",
                OAuthTokenSecret = "##########",
                UserID = ##########
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Don't catch an exception just to re-throw it.  You're clearing out the stack trace and adding no additional value.

Comment: @Servy, thanks. I'll keep that in mind- it was a temporary solution, though a bad one.

Comment: Just fyi I'm having trouble with the linqtotwitter streaming API just in the last day; everything was working fine before with the same binaries. Not sure if there's a problem with the library wrt some twitter update or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened to the answer that was here before, by @JoeMayo, but the thing that worked for me was to change the `AspNetAuthorizer` to `SingleUserAuthorizer`.

```
private static SingleUserAuthorizer GetCredentials()
{
    return new SingleUserAuthorizer
    {
        CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore()
        {
            ConsumerSecret = "##########",
            ConsumerKey = "##########",
            OAuthToken = "##########",
            OAuthTokenSecret = "##########",
            UserID = ##########
        }
    };
}
```

Also, I added `await auth.AuthorizeAsync();`

```
var auth = GetCredentials();

await auth.AuthorizeAsync();
```

As I said, the credit should really go to @JoeMayo, but his answer is gone.